# How would I add runs to this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to add something to detect runs/sequence into my program. A run is a sequence of adjacent repeated values. So the goal of the program is to create a string of 20 numbers (within the range of 1-6) and detect runs and put () around the runs, so for example 1 2 (5 5) 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 (5 5) 6 3 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
    int[] number = new int[20];       

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        number[i] = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1);
    }

    System.out.println("If you want to see all of the runs return R, if you only want to see the Longest return L");
    String input = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("The array is: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));     

    if (input.equals("r") || input.equals("R")) { 
        System.out.println("All of the runs are");         
    }     
}
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  We are not a code-writing service.

Comment: Where's your code for checking for sequences?

Comment: I don't know where/how to start. @TrippKinetics

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to work the logic on getting to sequences by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the following:

- Have a flag for whether or not a sequence has started
- A for-loop, traversing through your numbers array

In the for-loop

1. Check if the next number in the array is equal to the current
2. If it is the same, start a sequence
3. Add current number to your output
4. Check if the next number in the array is equal  to the current
5. If it is *not* the same, and a sequence is in progress, end the
   sequence
6. Repeat

Of course, starting a sequence would mean you'd have to add a starting parenthesis, while ending a sequence you'd add ending parenthesis.

Example:

```
public void outputSequence() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int[] numbers = new int[20];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) numbers[i] = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;

    boolean startPar = false;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Sequence: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if(i != 19 && numbers[i] == numbers[i+1] && !startPar) {
            output.append("( ");
            startPar = true;
        }

        output.append(numbers[i] + " ");

        if(i != 19 && numbers[i] != numbers[i+1] && startPar) {
            output.append(") ");
            startPar = false;
        }
    }

    if(startPar) output.append(")");

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Start of as primitive as you can. How would you find the runs in your array? You look at the first number and compare it to the second one, if it matches ur run has started, so u need to compare it to the third etc... If it doesnt match u start to look at the second number.
I would use a StringBuilder to add the "(" ")" Symbols and maybe parse the result String in the end to find the longest run. Or u can save the "record run" in another variable.